# how to use variables as input for embed message? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I got a question how to use a variable as a input for an embed message. When somebody message: asl hey @somebody 123, I want that the bot sends a embed message with the information given. I already made a script that haves args, so messageA{arg1} etc but now i want to use it in the embed message.

I tried this:

```
  if(msg.content === "test9") {
    const examplesEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    const args = msg.content.trim().split(/ +/g);
      let bericht = args[0]; // Remember arrays are 0-based!.
      let noemen = args[1];
      let pers = args[2]
    
  .setTitle('Info about your request')
    .setAuthor({ name: 'Jordy'})
    .setDescription('Self-made bot "by jordy" self scripted etc. Yes even this :')
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Regular field title', value: bericht},
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
    )
    .addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
    .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({ text: 'Some footer text here', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png' });
  msg.channel.send({ embeds: [examplesEmbed] });
  }
})


In an other script its the A has value for ' hello' but I get an error. how do I fix this?
```

Comment: its now putting test9 as value for title how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is quite simple, in order to use variables within strings in JS, you must use backticks (`).

You can use either of the following instead:

```js
    { name: 'Regular field title', value: `${messageA}` },
```

```js
    { name: 'Regular field title', value: messageA },
```

Comment: hey thanks, now the code cant read : setTitle, because when i use " ; " after args[2] it doesnt work at all. how do i fix this?

Comment: Put `examplesEmbed` right before `.setTitle` and it should work fine!

Comment: now i got it but its putting "test9" as title instead of message, how can i fix that?